# Google calendars not showing on iPad calendar

Tags: calendar, google

My Google calendars have stopped showing up on my iPad calendar, after many months of working properly. When you tap 'Calendars' at the bottom of the app, they're not listed.

I've tried deleting the Google account, and reinstalling. The setting for calendars in the account settings is definitely switched on.

I have been to calendar.google.com/calendar/syncselect and switched off all accounts, and switched them all back on.

But still nothing shows up in the calendar after several hours.

I'm at a loss to know what to do.

Running an iPad Air with iOS 9.3.2.